# Pass this object into event handler

Tags: java, android

I got the code below how do I pass the current object "this" into the event handler so that I can pass it to the object Foo:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(this) {
public void onClick(View view) {
   new Foo(this).AlertBox("Hello Lennie!");
}
});
```

Where "this" is: android.app.Activity

i get an error that it can't find the constructor:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Foo(android.app.Activity.this).AlertBox(...)
```